# CSS transition animation not displaying

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

Ello all. Thanks for reading and responding!

I am trying to alter the height over a div on hover to show more content that's cutoff by an overflow:hidden (tried text-overflow ellipsis but that failed miserably.. different task though!) I have the hover property working fine, however I'd like to include a transition animation as just jumping open a div is quite distracting. Alas no such luck.

Can't quite figure out where I'm failing though.

```
.technique_container{
width: 595px;
height: auto;
}

.techpic {
padding: 15px 0px 5px 10px;
width: 15%;
float: left;
height: 100px;
}
.techpic img {border-radius: 15%; margin-top: 15px;}

.technique {
width: 80%;
margin-left: 110px;
height: 118px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 1.0s; /* Animation time */
    -webkit-transition: height 1.0s; /* For Safari */
}

.technique:hover {height: auto;}
```

Seems like a basic CSS property but something is missing?

Also this is a great resource http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/K6zCT/ :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is that example correct? I don't see an element with class `technique`.

Comment: That link is to a resource, not the code in question. @JoshCrozier

Comment: The link is just to a resource I was using as reference :) Does not contain anything of mine or the above content

Comment: @BR89 Well, your problem is that you can't transition an element to a height of `auto`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Comment: @JoshCrozier Gah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the heads up. Sadly all the heights are variable depending on the amount of content. Some have 3 lines, some have 20. Probably no work around without JQuery then. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BR89 said, you cannot transition an element to a *`height`* of `auto`, but you can transition it to a **`max-height`**.

```
.technique {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 110px;
    max-height: defaultHeight;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 1.0s; /* Animation time */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.0s; /* For Safari */
}

.technique:hover {max-height: someLargeNumber;}
```

---

**Note:** `someLargeNumber` must exceed `.technique`'s maximum possible height (ie. `9999px`)

(http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't transition to `height:auto;`. I've had some success transitioning `max-height` instead (replacing `height:auto` with `max-height:900px;` or some number that definitely is greater than the intended height).

Comment: If it were just one div that'd be a great work around. Unfortunately I have about 15 of these guys stacked up with varying levels of content. Setting one max-height for all of them would be an eye sore for expanding divs that only have 5 lines of text

Comment: I feel you.  jQuery's probably your best bet.  [Bootstrap's Collapse Plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) is pretty handy in that case, honestly. (Requires their Transitions plugin too.)